# Angular http response.length returning undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to read the .length property of an http response but i am getting undefined. Here is the response i am getting from my backend

```
{
"departments": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "department_name": "Account",
        "department_code": "001"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "department_name": "Sales",
        "department_code": "002"
    }
 ]
}
```

My http request;

```
getDepartments(): Observable<Department[]> {

const url =  `${this.BASE_URL}/tenant/departments`;
return this.http.get<Department[]>(url, requestOptions);

}
```

Here is my Department interface

```
export interface Department {

  id: number;
  department_name: string;
  department_code : string;
}
```

Then in my component;

```
getDepartments(){
this.adminService.getDepartments().subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.departments = response;
  }
)
}
```

I already tried to map the response like thus;

```
  const url =  `${this.BASE_URL}/tenant/departments`;
return this.http.get<Department[]>(url, requestOptions).pipe(
  map(response => response.departments)
);
```

But then i get property departments does not exist on type Department[]

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this:

```
const url =  `${this.BASE_URL}/tenant/departments`;
return this.http.get<{departments:Department[]}>(url, requestOptions).pipe(
  map(response => response.departments)
);
```

so your response type actually matches your response